# List printers on the client side (Java)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, printing

I have an application running on the server and I want to be able to detect the printers that are accessible from any computer.

That is, on the client side I want the printers to be listed and now, as the application is running from a server, it shows the printers that are accessible from the server.

The idea is that from where you are going to access the application, that is, from any computer, you can list their respective printers.

I do not know if an option can be obtained by the IP address of that computer but I have not been able to find a way to solve it with what I have been doing this:

```
public List<String> printAvailable() {

        // busca los servicios de impresion...
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        //PrintService[] servicio= PrintServiceLookup

        List <String> Impresoras= new ArrayList<>();
        // -- ver los atributos de las impresoras...

        for (PrintService printService : services) {

            Impresoras.add(printService.getName());
            System.out.println(" ---- IMPRESORA: " + printService.getName());

            PrintServiceAttributeSet  printServiceAttributeSet= printService.getAttributes();


            System.out.println("--- atributos");

            // todos los atributos de la impresora
            Attribute[] a = printServiceAttributeSet.toArray();
            for (Attribute unAtribute : a) {
                System.out.println("atributo: " + unAtribute.getName());
            }

                    System.out.println("--- viendo valores especificos de los atributos ");

                    // valor especifico de un determinado atributo de la impresora
                    System.out.println("PrinterLocation: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(PrinterLocation.class));
                    System.out.println("PrinterInfo: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(PrinterInfo.class));
                    System.out.println("PrinterState: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(PrinterState.class));
                    System.out.println("Destination: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(Destination.class));
                    System.out.println("PrinterMakeAndModel: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(PrinterMakeAndModel.class));
                    System.out.println("PrinterIsAcceptingJobs: " + printServiceAttributeSet.get(PrinterIsAcceptingJobs.class));

        }
        return Impresoras;
}
```

Here I get the service that lists the printers but this does it where the application runs locally.

If you could give me a clue, I'd really appreciate it, because I do not know much about Java and I'm trying with examples.

Regards!

PD: I must print the printers through the application. Using the print option of the browser is not an option for me.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:javascript]?

Comment: The tag is in case it is possible on the client side it is possible to do it with javascript.

Comment: Windows has a list of avaiable printers to choose from, it comes out, if you choose to print, why does the server need to know that?

Comment: Hi! I'm not saying that the server needs to know that. I'm saying that my application runs on a server to be accessed from several computers via the web. I said the structure of what I have to print and that it behaves locally. That when accessing it from another computer is listing the printers that can be viewed from the server machine. And that from the application you can list the printers connected to any computer without showing the option to provide the browser to print. I explained?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you want to do.  Do you want to list another computer’s printers?  Do you want a server application to list the printers of a connected client?

Comment: @VGR Yes! As is. Since Javascript shows me only the print driver of the browser which I did not want. And there seems to be no other way

Comment: A server can’t directly inspect a client machine’s hardware.  You could set up your own protocol for the client communicating its available printers to the server.

Comment: @VGR maybe with threads or sockets?

Comment: A thread by itself will not connect to another machine, but you can certainly use sockets to communicate with clients.